# Adding double quotes to @ string

Tags: c#, string

As far as i understood, a string with an @ in required a set of double quotes to insert the quote in to the string?

I have tried that principle and to no avail. The following line works, but if i were to replace those strings with parameter values then i cant seem to get the correct compilation value

```
var node = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"//node[@label = ""Chemist Name""]/node[@label = ""John,Smith""]");
```

my attempt (of which i have tried several versions and ended up here, where i have now givn up !)

```
var node = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"//node[@label = " + ""+parentID+"" + "]/node[@label = " + ""+ name +"" + "]");
```

can anyone help me please?

Comment: var node = @"This is my string with two double quotes "" "" "; Console.WriteLine(node); outputs correctly. Have you tried creating your XPath string on its own and output to the console/debugger? You could try escaping the forward slashes of the XPath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing another double quote to close the string being appended and also @ before each string containing "".

Try this:

```
var node = 
 doc.SelectSingleNode(@"//node[@label = """ + parentID + @"""]/node[@label = """ + name + @"""]");
```

Comment: Corrected the code. @ was missing before each string that contains a "". Pls check it now.

Answer (score 5):

Use single quotes:

```
var node = doc.SelectSingleNode
               (@"//node[@label = 'Chemist Name']/node[@label = 'John,Smith']");

var node = doc.SelectSingleNode(
              string.format(@"//node[@label = '{0}']/node[@label = '{1}']"
                            , parentID, name));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var node = doc.SelectSingleNode(string.format(@"//node[@label = ""{0}""]/node[@label = ""{1}""]", parentId, name));
```

Comment: You are missing few quotes I think, ""{0}" -> ""{0}"" to put {0} in quotes, and ""{1} -> ""{1}"" for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

Write an extension method to extend string:

```
public static string Quote(this string input)
{
    return string.Format(@"""{0}""", input);
}
```

And then use it as follows:

```
var node = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"//node[@label = " + parentID.Quote() + "]/node[@label = " + name.Quote()  + "]");
```

Or simply:

```
 var node = doc.SelectSingleNode(string.Format(@"//node[@label = {0}"]/node[@label = {1}"]",parentID.Quote(), name.Quote());
```